# Expectation and Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning

> Let {$N(t),t\geq0$} be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$.
>   Calculate $E[N(t).N(t+s)]$

I know that $N(t)\sim Poisson(\lambda t)$ and $N(t+s)\sim Poisson(\lambda(t+s))$

I can assume that $N(t)$ and $N(t+s)$ are independent?

I do not see another way to do it, unless there is some trick.

**EDIT:** $$E[N(t).N(t+s)]=E[N(t)(N(t+s)-N(t))+N(t)N(t)]$$
$$=E[N(t)(N(t+s)-N(t))]+E[N(t)^2]$$
since $N(t)$ and $N(t+s)-N(t)$ are independent
$$E[N(t)(N(t+s)-N(t)]=E[N(t)].E[N(s)]=\lambda^2ts$$

where $\big(N(t+s)-N(t)\big)\sim Poisson(\lambda s)$

If $N(t)\sim Poisson(\lambda t)$ then $E[N(t)^2]=\lambda t+\lambda^2t^2$ then
$$E[N(t).N(t+s)]=\lambda^2ts+\lambda^2t^2+\lambda t=\lambda t(\lambda ts+\lambda t+1)$$

Comment: "I can assume that N(t) and N(t+s) are independent?" Not at all. What is your source on Poisson processes?

Comment: @Did Lecture notes and some things I find on the internet. I have this book [Ross](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Models-Tenth-Edition/dp/0123756863) too, but particularly I did not like it.I'm finding Poisson process much more difficult to learn than Markov chains.

Comment: WP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Definition. Ross (9th edition): Definition 5.1 page 304 "increments are independent". Is the word "increment" the problem?

Comment: @Did Independent increment don't mean $N(t)$ and $N(t\pm s)$ are independent?

Comment: No, the increment of the process between times $t$ and $t+s$ is $N(t+s)-N(t)$. "Independent increments" means that the increments on every disjoint intervals are independent, for example, $N(t+s)-N(t)$ and $N(t)-N(0)=N(t)$ are independent, being increments on $(t,t+s]$ and $(0,t]$ respectively.

Comment: Error sign in the Edit.

Comment: Very last formula wrong, previous-to-last ok.

Comment: @Did What is wrong?

Comment: Unless lambda=1, the very last equal sign is wrong (quadratics in lambda equals linear function of lambda? No, Sir!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N(t)$ and $N(t+s)$ are not independent. On the other hand, $N(t)$ and $N(t+s)-N(t)$ are independent. Moreover, $N(t)N(t+s) = N(t)[N(t+s)-N(t)] + N(t)N(t)$. Now use linearity of expectation and independence. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I did here, but do not know if it's right because I have no resolution.

Comment: So post what you got.

Comment: If you can take a look in the last edit, thank you.

Comment: @JohnSheridan: In your edit you seem to think $E[N(t)N(t)]=E[N(t)]^2$. This is false.

Comment: True, $N(t)$ is a random variable $E[N(t)N(t)]=Var(N(t))+E[N(t)]^2$ right?

Comment: @JohnSheridan: Yes.